# Как задать диапазон значений number

Tags: typescript

Как создать тип для числа, которое может меняться от 0 до 33 без конструкций if else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как частичное решение можно использовать [Tail-Recursion Elimination on Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types).
К сожалению работает только для целых чисел, с дробными не получиться.

```
type Enumerate<N extends number, Acc extends number[] = []> = Acc['length'] extends N
  ? Acc[number]
  : Enumerate<N, [...Acc, Acc['length']]>

type NumberRange<F extends number, T extends number> = Exclude<Enumerate<T>, Enumerate<F>>

type T = NumberRange<20, 30>

const a: T = 10; // type '10' is not assignable to type 'T'
const b: T = 20;
const c: T = 30; // type '30' is not assignable to type 'T'
const d: T = 40; // type '40' is not assignable to type 'T'
const f: T = 20.5; // type '20.5' is not assignable to type 'T'
```

Comment: Супер, мне и нужно с целыми числами). Спасибо